# Repeat script with different string - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with a number of countries;

```
Date         Qatar  Norway . . . 
 
01/01/2004   43      33
.
.
.
31/12/2021  32       32 . . .
```

I need each column to be its' own dataframe and in a pivot table which is fine and I am using the following;

```
Qatar = df[['Date', 'Qatar']]
Qatar['Date']= pd.to_datetime(Qatar['Date']) 
Qatar = Qatar.groupby([Qatar.Date.dt.year,Qatar.Date.dt.month]).mean()
Qatar = Qatar.unstack()
Qatar = Qatar/1745
Qatar = Qatar.round()
Cell('Exports_Country','D3').df = Qatar
```

I have 40+ countries, is there any way to write the above for the list of countries without doing it manually??

I had tried this;

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, 'Date', var_name='country', value_name='val')
df1['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) 
df2 = (df1.groupby(['country', df1.Date.dt.year,df1.Date.dt.month])['val']
           .mean()
           .unstack()
           .div(1745)
           .round())
```

but unfortunately the raw data it is pulling it changes quite a bit so the code needs to be dynamic enough to be referenced by the name of the country.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by first and third level:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, 'Date', var_name='country', value_name='val')
df1['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) 
df2 = (df1.groupby(['country', df1.Date.dt.year,df1.Date.dt.month])['val']
           .mean()
           .unstack([0,2])
           .div(1745)
           .round())

print (df2)
country Norway      Qatar     
Date        1    12    1    12
Date                          
2004       0.0  NaN   0.0  NaN
2021       NaN  0.0   NaN  0.0
```

So possible select columns by names:

```
Qatar = df2[['Qatar']]
print (Qatar)
country Qatar     
Date       1    12
Date              
2004      0.0  NaN
2021      NaN  0.0
```